# Automating SharePoint upload and download using script in Linux system

Tags: authentication, linux

I am new to SharePoint. I was trying to download and upload file using Perl script in a Linux machine but getting an "NTLM Authentication Error" while running the script.

I tried downloading the file using "wget" providing valid credentials through following command:

```
wget --user username --password passwd http://dest.sharepoint.com/Folder/file.txt
```

But got the error "`401 Unauthorized`". I am not able to identify the cause. The 401 error occurs when authentication is required and it is not provided whether it has failed or not. But in the above case username and password provided is correct,  because I am able to browse to the file using GUI in the browser with the same credentials.

If any one has any idea about this please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the configured authentication-method.
I.e. your method of access needs to be the same.

wget IMHO supports [basic, disgest and NTML authentication](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html). SharePoint 2013 supports (out-of-the-box) windows (i.e. NTLM), forms-based, and SAML-based claims authentication..

If your SharePoint WebApplication is configured to use **windows authentication**, wget NTLM should work. As should the `curl --ntlm`-command.

If your SharePoint is configured for **forms-based authentication**, you'll need to fake a login, and pass a cookie in your download-request. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget) for ideas on how to do this.

I have no idea, what you could do if the SharePoint is configured for **[SAML-based](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx) claims authentication**.

Answer (score 2):

I have also come across this issue. Added -k option to curl command such as:

```
curl -k --ntlm -u username:password -O http://dest.sharepoint.com/Folder/file.txt
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Please use rclone

Download and install the latest one from https://rclone.org/downloads

First option: Use OneDrive to access  SharePoint sites/personal folder. This option will help you to upload large files.

1.create rclone configurations using the `rclone config` command

2.Select New remote and give a name

3.Select cloud storage OneDrive

4.Leave client ID and secret as blank

5.Edit advanced config: n

6.Remote config: Use auto-config: y

7.Open the URL on the browser and give access to rclone

8.Select personal/shared site URL option

8a.Shared site URL option you have to give the site URL. ie; https://sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName

9.Select personal/Documents drive. Documents drive will show if you selected the shared site URL option in the 8th step

10. Save config and quit

And the configuration file contents will be like the following. If you selected the Personal option drive type will be personal.

```
[onedrive]
type = onedrive
token = 
drive_id = 
drive_type = documentLibrary
```

Second option: In this option, you can upload up to 2 GB-sized files.

1.create rclone configurations using `rclone config` command

2.Select New remote and give a name

3.Select cloud storage WebDAV

4.Give site URL, username and password

5.Save and quit

And the configuration file contents will be like the following. Password will be in an encrypted format.

`vim /root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf`

```
[sharepoint]
type = webdav
url = https://sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Documents
vendor = sharepoint
user = 
pass =
```

Download a file from SharePoint.

`rclone copy --ignore-times --ignore-size --verbose sharepoint:SourceFolder/file.txt  DestFolder`

Comment: Why configure as root?

Comment: You can use any user, but execute rclone command as that user otherwise configuration won't pick.

Answer (score 1):

thy curl :
`curl --ntlm -u username:password -O http://dest.sharepoint.com/Folder/file.txt`

Comment: not working 0 file downloaded

Comment: works fine here.  replace username with username@example.com format

Comment: @Eric I don't think this works. Check the contents of the file you downloaded is not an HTML error page, instead of the file you were expecting.

Comment: @Nick i have a test again just now, it works here. i get the correct file from sharepoint 2010 document library, using curl from osx.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found, is using Chrome's debugger tools.

In the network tab, you can 'catch' the request that is being done when you click `download` in SharePoint.

On this request, you can right-click, and `copy as curl`. This will copy the correct command (incl. the cookies/authentication headers) to your clipboard.

You can then past that command in your console and the file will download.